# AWS Codebuild buildspec.yaml not finding files

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-sam

]I have an aws pipeline set up for a lambda function service written in typescript. I am using sam for serverless deployment. In my buildspec.yaml I have a command that is suppose to run one of my pre built scripts in my package.json to compile typescript but the codebuild says there is no such file or directory.

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run compile
artifacts: 
  files:
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
```

```
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:00 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:04 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src071783151/src
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src071783151/src/config/buildspec.dev.yml
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 No runtime version selected in buildspec.
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src071783151/src
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Registering with agent
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Phases found in YAML: 1
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18  BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:18 Running command npm run compile
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /codebuild/output/src071783151/src/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src071783151/src/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-21T15_12_25_587Z-debug.log

[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Command did not exit successfully npm run compile exit status 254
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run compile. Reason: exit status 254
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Expanding base directory path: .
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Expanding .
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Expanding file paths for base directory .
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Expanding package.json
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Skipping invalid file path package.json
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Expanding package-lock.json
[Container] 2020/09/21 15:12:25 Skipping invalid file path package-lock.json
```

[[image: File Structure]]

Comment: make sure the .yml file is not in a subfolder and in the top level.

Comment: @PHPNoob I made that change and still got the same error.

Comment: can you show or describe your file structure?

Comment: @PHPNoob I have added a picture of my file structure

Comment: You have the buildspec in a folder, remove it out of the folder, for example it should be in the main directory like the `README.md` and `template.yaml` files are.

Comment: @PHPNoob I did that and still got the same error. I made sure to adjust the path in the console for the buildspec.

Comment: the last thing to try would be to remove the `dev` and just name it `buildspec.yml` what significance are you trying to represent with the `.dev` in the name convention?

Comment: @PHPNoob I was planning to add yml files for each environment: dev, test, qa and prod.

Comment: I do not think that is possible, I am pretty sure the name has to be `buildspec.yml`, unless you can show me the documentation that states otherwise.

Comment: "Buildspec name - optional
By default, CodeBuild looks for a file named buildspec.yml in the source code root directory. If your buildspec file uses a different name or location, enter its path from the source root here (for example, buildspec-two.yml or configuration/buildspec.yml)." -> This is a note from the console when creating a build project. @PHPNoob

Comment: I am an idiot apologies. I read the questions wrong, I thought codebuild was not finding the `buildspec` it cleary is. Okay so are the files making it to your artifacts bucket in s3? Because the cli in codebuild is in the correct directory from the log.

Comment: No. I assume when I run "sam deploy", the files will get uploaded to the bucket however, I haven't added that step in my buildspec because I can not get past compiling the code @PHPNoob

Comment: My only other try could be to make sure you are in the correct directory when running `npm run compile` for example sometimes in codebuild you are at root, so running `npm run` will fail so before you run the `npm`command make sure to `cd YOUR PROJECT FOLDER` first then `npm run compile`

Comment: I have same issue - my buildspec is part of my project - not in my source. But I changed the location to a fake url and it still showed in log as downloading source, yarn install successful and failed the build. So in my case its clearly not downloading anything and fails to error out